# Image never loads in nodeJs Azure function

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions

I have a use case where I want to use a nodeJs Azure function to use some existing JavaScript I have for generating some images by first drawing them onto a canvas element and then converting to base64 to be saved.

The issue I am having is due to nodeJS not having a browser, I am having to use JSDOM to be my DOM to load any images.

My test code looks as follows, this just never gets to finish loading the image, I am a bit stumped as to why, can anyone shed any light?

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(
  '<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><head></head><body id="abody" ></body></html>'
);
const window = dom.window;
const document = window.document;
const Image = window.Image;

module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
  var img = new Image();
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  await new Promise(function (complete, failed) {
    img.onload = function () {
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      console.log(png);
      complete(png);
    };

    img.src =
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg";
  });

  return;
};
```

Comment: Do you want to display the content on the browser? Can you explain your requirements?

Comment: I want to generate some images using an Azure node.js function.  I already have the code to do this using a browser, but when translating to node.js it doesn't load properly.  These images are to be saved to blob storage later on which are to them be displayed on my website.